# Store extra information depending on the role

Tags: database-design

I'm developing an app that has 2 BC:

1. The Identity and Access Context: Will contain a plenty of features like login, registration, roles... So, I will have two tables: identity (id, email and password), role (name, description), and identity_role (identity_id, role_id). I will have 3 type of role user, poster, admin
2. Forum BC: Each of those types of roles will do different types of activities. So, I think is would be fine to model each of those roles, for instance: User entity, Poster entity and Admin entity.

In the Forum BC I have to create a table that keep extra information of that person. At this moment every role is gonna have the same information, but maybe in the future I have some extra information that maybe admin has but no poster. So, I have two options:

1. Create a profile table to store the basic information of every role such as: identity_id, name, lastname, age... and if in the future I have to add some extra information I can add the property in the table and some of roles will have null because maybe they never are gonna have it.
2. Create a different table for every role like admin_profile, user_profile...

What do yo think about of this approach of BC? Which option is better?

Comment: DDD has nothing to do with how you store the data

Comment: Yes, I know it. I didn't say that. Somebody has idea about my two questions?

Comment: When you present us your architecture in terms of `tables` it means that you are not interested in DDD. Try to see the bigger picture, otherwise you will be stuck in tables and FK constraints.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful your answer.